# Import errors with pyusb in eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, usb, pydev, pyusb

I downloaded pyusb, but eclipse keeps giving me unresolved import errors.  I tried downloading the pyusb directories into the pydev interpreter library and importing the individual modules, neither of which solved the problem.

```
import usb.core
import usb.util
```